# How to get an item which is at the center of list view?

Tags: android, listview

I have listview ,I want to get item which is at the center of listview.

Example ListView 
Having 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 is visible on screen.Now on click of button I want 4(4 is at the cent of visible list) should get highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Do this inside `onClick()` method of the button.

```
int midItem = ((listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()) / 2) + 1;
View v = listView.getChildAt(midItem);
v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00); // Any color you want
```

It would highlight the item in mid of all visible items.